# How to extract a list of strings out of single string by using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, text-mining

I have a long string that is actually a set of concepts. I want to mine the string and to create a list of concepts.

The string begins with:

`Abduction and retroduction Action research: a case study Analysis of variance (ANOVA) Attitudes Autobiography see Biographical method...`

The list contains dictionary entries. In vast majority of cases the capital letters mark the beginning of new entry. I want to make a list of entries.

I have tried `re.findall(r"([A-Z].+?)\s[A-Z]")`. But it filters out every second entry. Instead of ["Abduction and retroduction", "Action research: a case study", "Analysis of variance (ANOVA)"] I get: ["Abduction and retroduction", "Analysis of variance (ANOVA)"]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you can have overlapping results, it is the reason why all second contiguous entry is skipped (since you match his first letter). A way to avoid this problem is to not match this first letter by using a lookahead assertion `(?=..)` that means "followed by" *(A lookahead is only a check and matches nothing)*:

```
re.findall(r"(\b[A-Z].+?)(?=\s[A-Z]|\s*$)")
```